# How to reload font file configuration in KDE5 plasma

Tags: kde, configuration, fonts, plasma, dpi

I'm trying to set font config in file `~/.config/kcmfonts`

```
cat > ~/.config/kcmfonts <<EOF
[General]
forceFontDPI=216
EOF
```

Then restart `plasmashell` and `kwin_x11`

```
plasmashell --replace &>/dev/null &
kwin_x11 --replace &>/dev/null &
```

But this gives no effects. How to reload this settings from command line?
It's equivalent to plasma 5.19 `System Settings → Appearance → Font → Fonts → Force fonts DPI`

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the cache of font directory with the following command:

`sudo fc-cache -f -v`

After that, restart your application and the font should be available.

Comment: Unfortunately above solution does not work.